# Laravel auto increment serial number

Tags: php, laravel, form-data

In laravel, I am fetching form data into blade view but I don't know how there is printing serial number on left upper side of my table, here is the code and screenshot. please help me . **I just want to add serial number like 1,2,3...**

```
<tbody>
                    {{ $sl = 1; }}

                    @foreach ($data as $data)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $sl }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $data->category_name }}</td>

                            <td> <a id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" href="">Edit</a>
                                <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this category?')"
                                    href="{{ url('delete_category', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {{ $sl ++ }}
                    @endforeach
  </tbody>

 here is the screenshot.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC2J8.png)

I tried to fix it by using core-php code, and getting this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use curly brackets in Laravel's Blade it's an equivalent of `echo()` in PHP. To fix this change your curly brackets to `@php` and `@endphp`.

```
<tbody>
    @php $sl = 1; @endphp
    @foreach ($data as $data)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ $sl }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data->category_name }}</td>
       </tr>
       @php $sl++ @endphp
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Even better if your `$data` variable is just a list or a collection, don't use in-template variables. Just iterate:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $index=>$data)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data->category_name }}</td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you sir,  my problem solved by using @php-@endphp where i was using {{ }}.

Answer (score 0):

You can check blade templates

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $item)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ $loop->index }}</td>
           <td>{{ $item->category_name }}</td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```